# why php codes doesn't work on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

when I insert this code or any other code in function.php file of child theme or tha parent theme ..there is no change occur and I don't know where is the problem
I need to remove "add to cart" button from some categories only
`
/* // Replace the Add to Cart Btn in Category Ammunition with View Product Btn  */

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','change_simple_shop_add_to_cart',10,2);
  function change_simple_shop_add_to_cart( $html, $product ){


       $category_ammunition = $product->get_categories();


      if (strstr($category_ammunition, 'Ammunition')) { // Add Your Category Here 'Ammuntion'

 $html = sprintf( '<a id="read-more-btn" rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-product_id="%s"  class="button vp-btn">%s</a>',
                  esc_url( get_the_permalink() ),
                  esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                  esc_html(  __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) )
          );
          $category_ammunition = $product->get_categories();
      }

      return $html;
  }`
```

I tried to activate the parent theme and add code in its function.php file and also there is no change occure